# RTK Query cache

Tags: rtk-query

If I don't use a `Cache tags` on RTK Query, will RTK Query cache my data?

See

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'

const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: '/',
  }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getPosts: build.query({
      query: () => '/posts',
    }),
    addPost: build.mutation({
      query: (body) => ({
        url: 'post',
        method: 'POST',
        body,
      }),
    }),
  }),
})
```

If I don't have a `tagTypes: ['Post'],`, will RTK Query the post data? And if I don't have a tagTypes, can I still use `providesTags` and `invalidatesTags`?

Answer (score 0):

Tags are not for caching, but for invalidation. So yes, queries (and to a certain extent, mutations) will be cached independently if you use them.

But you cannot provide or invalidate tags without tags.

Answer (score 0):

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/cache-behavior#default-cache-behavior

From the documentation

> When a subscription is started, the parameters used with the endpoint are serialized and stored internally as a queryCacheKey for the request.

All subscriptions/queries are cached using that queryCacheKey.

Meaning that whenever use...Query is called with **new** parameter a **new** request gets sent, otherwise if a queryCacheKey matches the one in store the cached data is used.

You can configure this behaviour using the `keepUnusedDataFor` parameter on `createApi` or each endpoint individually.

The tags are used for Automatic re-fetching so making the success/error of a query/mutation trigger a refetch on another query endpoint by invalidating the tag of that given endpoint. Usually a mutation is made to invalidate tags of a quer